# Nonnegative graphic integers proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $d = (d_{1}, d_{2},...,d_{n})$ be a sequence of nonnegative integers that is graphic. Prove that for each integer k = $1,2,...,n$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^kd_{i} \leq k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \min \{k,d_{i}\}. 
$$

I am not exactly sure on how to proceed. I know that a graphic sequence is a sequence of numbers which can be the degree sequence of some graph (from Wolfram). I am still quite new to this topic, so I thought of using mathematical induction, but the base case $\sum_{i=1}^1d_{i} = d_{1} \leq 1(1-1) + \sum_{i=2}^n \min \{1,d_{i}\}$ already seems complicated. Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: fix a graph with those degrees. $\sum_{i=1}^kd_i$ counts the number of edge-ends meeting the first $k$ vertices. Every edge-end counted is either from an edge between two vertices in the first $k$, or between one of these vertices and one of the other vertices.